# Datable sorting by specific column by function argument

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have following js function:

```
function addDatatable(orderArray) {
$('.Table').dataTable({
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
    } ],
 ...
```

I call this function on many jsp files, but on every page I would like to have another ordering. How I can send into the function specific order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data-*` attributes for each `table` to define ordering if there are multiple tables and their configuration is the same besides ordering.

```
<table id="example" class="display" data-order="[[ 3, &quot;desc&quot; ]]" width="100%">
```

See [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html) for code and demonstration.